# how to move on same link by clicking on a multiple button of same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
        for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            $("#body").append("<div id=myIdh> Job Title</div></div>").append("<div id=myId><div id=myId1 ></div><div id=myId3 >Job Discription</div><div id=b>'<button id=b1 >Update</button><button id=b1>Delete</button></div></div>");
        }


        });
        $('#b1').click(function(){
        window.location="index.html";
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: my code is:<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
  for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {
   $("#body").append("<div id=myIdh> Job Title</div></div>").append("<div id=myId><div id=myId1 ></div><div id=myId3 >Job Discription</div><div id=b>'<button id=c"+i+" >Update</button><button id=b1>Delete</button></div></div>");
  }
  
  
  });
  $('#c1').click(function(){
  window.location="index.html";
  });
  </script>

Comment: don't post code in comments.Add it to your question

Comment: Please provide a proper problem description. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Although you should not use the same id twice in a page. it is not good practice. but if it is your requirement than you can try the below code for button click and use attribute selector.

```
$('#body').on('click', '[id="b1"]',function(){
    window.location="index.html";
});
```